# How to filter Bare metal response from network gateway appliances response?

Tags: json, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, bare-metal-server

In the Response of IBM Bare-Metal server API we are getting the response of Network gateway appliances also . Is there Any way to filter the response of Bare metal from network gateway appliances. 
API for getting Bare metal server is `HTTP://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware.`

Answer (score 0):

When you call the getHardware method, it returns all bare metal servers in which you will get the gateway appliances because they are bare metal servers too.

Now to get the network gateway appliances in the account you have to use [SoftLayer_Account::getNetworkGateways](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkGateways/)

This method will return only the network gateway appliances and their hardware [members](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Gateway_Member/). I think this is what you are looking for.

To get this information use the following rest api:

Method: GET

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkGateways?objectMask=mask[members[hardware]]
```

To get the list of hardware data for a specific network gateway you can use this rest api example:

Method: GET

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Gateway/$GatwayID/getObject?objectMask=mask[members[hardware]]
```